# Insert statement terminated in VB6 [error 01000 Microsoft ODBC] when using Windows 10

Tags: sql, vb6

My VB6 application runs OK in Windows 7 but generates an error in Windows 10. The error message is:

> error 01000: microsoft ODBC

When I debug in Windows 10, Windows can't execute my `insert` statement. My ODBC connection is OK. I think Windows 10 can't handle long statement. Please help me solve this problem.

This is the code to save and insert data into database:

```
Set InsertData = New rdoQuery
Set InsertData.ActiveConnection = conndtrs
InsertData.SQL = "insert into downtime (dt_date,dt_info1,dt_shop,dt_shift, " & _
                "dt_model,dt_region,dt_category,dt_sub_category,dt_time, " & _
                "dt_details,dt_caseno,dt_responsible,day_night,dt_time1,user_id," & _
                "dt_keyin,dt_meeting,Dt_Company,dt_ct_measure,area) " & _
                " values ('" & Dt_Date & "','" & dt_info1 & "','" & dt_shop & "', " & _
                "'" & dt_shift & "','" & dt_model & "','" & Dt_Region & "','" & dt_category & "', " & _
                "'" & dt_sub_category & "'," & dt_time & ",'" & dt_details & "'," & newlk_caseno & ", " & _
                "'" & dt_responsible & "','" & day_night & "','" & dt_time1 & "','" & user_id & "', " & _
                "'" & dt_keyin & "','Y','PEMSB','" & dt_ct_measure & "','" & Area & "')"

InsertData.Execute

MsgBox ("Data saved.....")
```

Data is saved to a SQL 2000 database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in the insert query. May be the date format is wrongly specified. That is the reason this errors arises. Specify the date format as:-

```
  Format(date,"dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

After turning on ODBC logging got the event message, A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013. This did lead me to the fix from a similar error.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client\ Enabled needed to be flipped from 0 to 1
```